# Python pandas - merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataset called df. I am trying to construct a dataframe that shows the share of each group  for each possible outcome. Meaning, I have a list that specifies the columns to group by the dataframe, and a column that specifies the outcome of interest.

The columns contained in this dataset are:

```
['stop_id', 'stop_date', 'officer_id', 'driver_gender', 'driver_age', 'driver_race', 'ethnicity', 'violation', 'is_arrested', 'stop_outcome','stop_year', 'stop_month', 'stop_season', 'age_category', 'arrest_or_citation'].
```

And df looks like this (I copied first 15 rows):
    df[:15]

```
stop_id  stop_date        ...         age_category arrest_or_citation
 0   2168033 2004-05-29        ...          middle_aged              False
 1   4922383 2009-09-04        ...          young_adult              True
 2   5109631 2009-12-23        ...          middle_aged              True
 3   924766 2001-08-13        ...                adult               True
 4   2293870 2004-09-25        ...          middle_aged               True
 5   2294412 2004-09-26        ...          young_adult               True
 6   6224320 2011-05-11        ...          young_adult               True
 7   2773342 2006-01-30        ...          middle_aged              False
 8   8559541 2014-05-25        ...             juvenile               True
 9   9089078 2015-04-01        ...          middle_aged               True
 10    58220 2000-02-09        ...                adult               True
 11  7449910 2012-10-30        ...          middle_aged               True
 12  9229308 2015-06-15        ...          young_adult               True
 13  4257690 2008-08-24        ...          young_adult               True
 14  3964626 2008-03-27        ...                adult               True
 15  8017683 2013-08-13        ...          middle_aged               True

 [15 rows x 15 columns]
```

As an example, I am trying to group by ['age_category', 'driver_gender'] and get each group's share in 'is_arrested']. The dataframe I should arrive at should look like this:

```
 is_arrested                    False     True
 age_category driver_gender
 juvenile     F              0.994462  0.005538
              M              0.984669  0.015331
 young_adult  F              0.990855  0.009145
              M              0.979265  0.020735
 adult        F              0.991970  0.008030
              M              0.983174  0.016826
 middle_aged  F              0.995749  0.004251
              M              0.989827  0.010173
 senior       F              0.998697  0.001303
              M              0.995823  0.004177
```

However, I am not able to do so. I tried:

```
 size_per_group = df.groupby(['age_category', 'driver_gender'])['is_arrested'].size()

 size_per_group_outcome = df.groupby(['age_category', 'driver_gender', 'is_arrested'])['is_arrested'].size()

 df_share = size_per_group_putcome/size_per_group
```

But this results in:

```
 NotImplementedError: merging with more than one level overlap on a multi-index is not implemented
```

I am not able to fix it, and would appreciate any help on this! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there, I think you just need to use `.mean()` in this case, which will give you the % of times `arrested` was `True`. A short example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 1000

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'age': np.random.choice(['young_adult', 'middle_aged', 'adult', 'juvenile'], n),
        'gender': np.random.choice(['M', 'F'], n),
        'arrested': np.random.rand(n) > .95
    }
)

print(data.groupby(['age', 'gender'])['arrested'].mean())

age          gender
adult        F         0.065421
             M         0.042254
juvenile     F         0.024390
             M         0.055172
middle_aged  F         0.019417
             M         0.064516
young_adult  F         0.029851
             M         0.016393
```

To get a frequency count of `True` and `False` occurrences (seems a little redundant but anyway), you can used `.crosstab()` with index normalization:

```
pd.crosstab([data['age'], data['gender']], data['arrested'], normalize = 'index')
```

Giving:

```
arrested               False     True 
age         gender                    
adult       F       0.965986  0.034014
            M       0.950000  0.050000
juvenile    F       0.945312  0.054688
            M       0.900901  0.099099
middle_aged F       0.934579  0.065421
            M       0.942857  0.057143
young_adult F       0.966942  0.033058
            M       0.936508  0.063492
```

Note: the results of the two approaches don't match, as I regenerated the random data.

Comment: Thank you! Although I need both the false and true values, like the table I showed above. The is_arrested column has boolean true and false values specified for each observation. Your code only returns the true values as opposed to the share of both true and false values for each gender under each age group. Do you have any idea how could I achieve that? Thank you!